# How do I access AS/400 using SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, db2-400

**Short version:**  *Please tell me how to connect to AS/400s via SQLAlchemy.*

**Long version**

My ultimate goal is to join data from SQL Server and AS/400 to be displayed in a Flask Python application.  My approach has been to get the data from each database into Pandas dataframes, which can then be joined and output as JSON.  If anyone has a better approach, feel free to leave a comment.  The problem with the way I'm trying to do this is that `Pandas.read_sql_query()` relies on SQLAlchemy, and getting SQLAlchemy to work with AS/400 is proving quite difficult.

- The AS/400 is version 7.2, though another I will likely try to connect to is version 5.1.
- I'm trying to access it from my computer, which is running Windows 7 and has i Access 7.1, Python 2.7, and Python modules including `pyodbc` and `ibm_db_sa`.

**Without `sqlalchemy`, `pyodbc` works just fine:**

```
CONNECTION_STRING = (
    "driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};"
    "system=ip_address;"
    "database=database_name;"
    "uid=username;"
    "pwd=password;"
) 
pyodbc.connect(CONNECTION_STRING)
# Queries work fine after this.
```

I've read these resources, among others, and tried to apply their techniques:

- https://pypi.org/project/ibm_db_sa/
- [Connecting to IBM AS400 server for database operations hangs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35461388/connecting-to-ibm-as400-server-for-database-operations-hangs)
- [SqlAlchemy equivalent of pyodbc connect string using FreeTDS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4493614/sqlalchemy-equivalent-of-pyodbc-connect-string-using-freetds)

Below are some of the failed attempts and corresponding error messages that I've collected.  I don't know what to put for the first part ("`something+something//...`"), which port to specify (446? 8471? something else? nothing?), whether to use the server's name or IP address, or whether to use the connection-string style argument for `create_engine()`, so I've just been trying every combination I can think of.  I tried modifying the `AS400Dialect_pyodbc` class as suggested in the second link above, after which I tried rerunning some of the failed attempts again.  I may keep trying things, but I'm just spinning my wheels at this point.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

CONNECTION_STRING = (
    "driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};"
    "system=ip_address;"
    "database=database_name;"
    "uid=username;"
    "pwd=password;"
)

create_engine('ibm_db_sa+pyodbc://username:password@ip_address:446/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
>   (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', u'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 43, in

```
create_engine('ibm_db_sa://username:password@ip_address:446/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "database_name           " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004\r SQLCODE=-30061 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 43, in

```
create_engine('ibm_db_sa://username:password@server_name:446/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1336N  The remote host "server_name" was not found.  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-1336 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8create_engine('ibm_db_sa://username:password@ip_address:446/server_name.database_name').connect()

```
create_engine('ibm_db_sa://username:password@ip_address:446/server_name.database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "server_name.database_name  " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004\r SQLCODE=-30061 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

```
create_engine('db2+ibm_db://username:password@ip_address:446/server_name.database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "server_name.database_name  " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004\r SQLCODE=-30061 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 45, in

```
create_engine('db2+ibm_db://username:password@ip_address:446/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "database_name           " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004\r SQLCODE=-30061 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 45, in

```
create_engine('db2+ibm_db://username:password@ip_address/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "ip_address".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10061", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-30081 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

```
create_engine('db2+ibm_db://username:password@server_name:446/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1336N  The remote host "server_name" was not found.  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-1336 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

```
create_engine('db2+ibm_db://username:password@server_name/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL1336N  The remote host "server_name" was not found.  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-1336 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)

```
create_engine('db2+pyodbc://username:password@ip_address:446/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
>   (pyodbc.InterfaceError) ('IM002', u'[IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data source name not found and no default driver specified (0) (SQLDriverConnect)') (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 45, in

```
create_engine('db2://username:password@ip_address:446/database_name').connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.OperationalError) ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30061N  The database alias or database name "database_name           " was not found at the remote node.  SQLSTATE=08004\r SQLCODE=-30061 (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/e3q8)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 45, in

```
quoted = urllib.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)
create_engine('ibm_db_sa+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)).connect()
```

> Unable to open 'hashtable_class_helper.pxi': File not found
>   (file:///c:/git/dashboards/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi).

```
quoted = urllib.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)
create_engine('ibm_db_sa:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)).connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.InterfaceError) ibm_db_dbi::InterfaceError: connect expects the first five arguments to be of type string or unicode (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 43, in

```
quoted = urllib.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)
create_engine('ibm_db:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)).connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError
>   Cant load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db

```
quoted = urllib.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)
create_engine('db2:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)).connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.InterfaceError) ibm_db_dbi::InterfaceError: connect expects the first five arguments to be of type string or unicode (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)
>     File "C:\Git\dashboards\web_app\pandas db2 test.py", line 45, in

```
quoted = urllib.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)
create_engine('db2+ibm_db:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)).connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.InterfaceError
>   (ibm_db_dbi.InterfaceError) ibm_db_dbi::InterfaceError: connect expects the first five arguments to be of type string or unicode (Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/rvf5)

```
quoted = urllib.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)
create_engine('db2+ibm_db_sa:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted)).connect()
```

> Exception has occurred: sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError
>   Cant load plugin: sqlalchemy.dialects:db2.ibm_db_sa

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I finally got it working, though it's a bit awkward.  I created a blank file in my project to appease this message that I was receiving in response to one of the attempts shown in my question:

> Unable to open `'hashtable_class_helper.pxi'`: File not found (`file:///c:/git/dashboards/pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi`).

(My project folder is `C:/Git/dashboards`, so I created the rest of the path.)

With that file present, the code below now works for me.  `engine.connect()` works, but I ran an actual query for further verification that it was working.  For the record, it seems to work regardless of whether the `ibm_db_sa` module is modified as suggested in one of the links in my question, so I would recommend leaving that module alone.  Note that although they aren't imported directly, you need these modules installed: `pyodbc`, `ibm_db_sa`, and possibly `future` (I forget).

```
import urllib
import pandas as pd
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

CONNECTION_STRING = (
    "driver={iSeries Access ODBC Driver};"
    "system=ip_address;"
    "database=database_name;"
    "uid=username;"
    "pwd=password;"
)

SQL= """\
SELECT
    MPBASE AS BASEPA,
    COALESCE(SUM(MPQTY), 0) AS PWIP
FROM FUTMODS.MPPROD
WHERE MPOPT <> '*'
GROUP BY MPBASE
"""

quoted = urllib.quote_plus(CONNECTION_STRING)
engine = create_engine('ibm_db_sa+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect={}'.format(quoted))

df = pd.read_sql_query(
    SQL,
    engine,
    index_col='basepa'
)
print df
```