# Can read but not write to as/400 database with python

Tags: python, pandas, sqlalchemy, pyodbc, ibm-midrange

I have a problem setting which involves data manipulation on an IBMi as/400 database. I'm trying to solve the problem with the help of python and pandas.

For the last days I'm was trying to set up a proper connection to the as/400 db which every combination of package, driver, dialect whatsoever that I could find on SO or Google.
Neither of the solutions is fully working for me. Some are better, while others are not working at all.

Here's the current situation:

I'm able to read and write data through `pyodbc`. The connection string I'm using is the following:

```
cstring = urllib.parse.quote("DRIVER={IBM i Access ODBC Driver};SYSTEM=IP;UID=XXX;PWD=YYY;PORT=21;CommitMode=0;SIGNON=4;CCSID=1208;TRANSLATE=1;")
```

Then I establish the connection like so:

```
connection = pypyodbc.connect(cstring)
```

With `connection` I can read and write data from/to the as400 db through raw SQL statements:

```
connection.execute("""CREATE TABLE WWNMOD5.temp(
    store_id INT GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY NOT NULL,
    store_name VARCHAR(150),
    PRIMARY KEY (store_id)
)""")
```

This is, of course, a meaningless example. My goal would be to write a pandas DataFrame to the as400 by using

```
df.to_sql()
```

But when trying to do something like this:

```
df.to_sql('temp', connection, schema='WWNMOD5', chunksize=1000, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I get this error:

```
pandas.io.sql.DatabaseError: Execution failed on sql 'SELECT name FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name=?;': ('42000', '[42000] [IBM][System i Access ODBC-Treiber][DB2 für i5/OS]SQL0104 - Token ; ungÃ¼ltig. GÃ¼ltige Token: <ENDE DER ANWEISUNG>.')
```

Meaning that an invalid token was used which in this case I believe is the ';' at the end of the SQL statement.

I believe that pandas isn't compatible with the pyodbc package. Therefore, I was also trying to work with the db over sqlalchemy.
With sqlalchemy, I establish the connection like so:

```
engine= sa.create_engine("iaccess+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s"%cstring)
```

I also tried to use `ibm_db_sa` instead of `iaccess` but the result is always the same.
If I do the same from above with sqlalchemy, that is:

```
df.to_sql('temp', engine, schema='WWNMOD5', chunksize=1000, if_exists='append', index=False)
```

I don't get any error message but the table is not created either and I don't know why.

Is there a way how to get this working? All the SO threads are only suggesting solutions for establishing a connection and reading data from as400 databases but don't cover writing data back to the as400 db via python.

Comment: You write you have no error but the table is not created in the last part. How did you check ? Did you try `select * from WWNMOD5.temp` AND `select * from WWNMOD5."temp"` ?

Comment: I'm checking this with DBeaver which doesn't display the table.
But also, when trying to get the table through raw SQL statement, I don't get a result back. I don't get an error in this case as well. But cannot fetch the data entries from the table neither. So `fetchall()` is printing nothing.

Comment: your error says `FROM sqlite_master`  ... which isn't a table I'd expect to see on on IBM i

Comment: Can you add the result of `select ordinal_position, message_id,message_text from table(JOBLOG_INFO(qsys2.job_name)) order by ordinal_position desc` executed in the same connection as the create table tha does not return an error, after it has been executed ?

Comment: Still no output for this statement. However, with the connection with which I get some output, I get the following (in german):
`[(5, 'SQL799C', 'Die folgenden Sonderregister wurden festgelegt: CLIENT_APPLNAME: PYTHON'), (4, 'CPF1301', 'Abrechnungsdaten für 272442/QUSER/QZDASOINIT nicht protokolliert; Ursache: 1.'), (3, 'CPIAD02', 'Benutzer UID an Client IP ist mit dem Server verbunden.'), (2, 'CPF1301', 'Abrechnungsdaten für 272442/QUSER/QZDASOINIT nicht protokolliert; Ursache: 1.'), (1, 'CPF1124', 'Job 272442/QUSER/QZDASOINIT im Subsystem QUSRWRK in QSYS am 04.02.22 um 10:20:13 gestartet.`

Comment: +
`Job im System am 04.02.22 um 10:20:13. angekommen.')]`

Comment: Did you read my response to your comment on [my answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35494302/95852)?

Comment: Yes, I have read your answer.
I don't know about SQLAlchemy dropping the error msg somewhere on the way. Could be.
Regarding Commitment Control, I feel that I have covered that problem. Earlier I had the problem that I couldn't write at all to our as/400 with any connection due to some journaling issues, I believe. That's why I set the option `CommitMode=0` for the `pyodbc` connection. After that I can write to the db using plain SQL statements. Is it that what you had in mind? If so, I believe I have sorted out this issue, otherwise I still couldn't write.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong driver. Pandas claims support for any DB supported by SQLAlchemy. But in order for SQLAlchemy to use DB2, it needs a third party extension.

This is the one recommended by SQLAlchemy: https://pypi.org/project/ibm-db-sa/

Comment: You mean changing
`engine= sa.create_engine("iaccess+pyodbc:///?odbc_connect=%s"%cstring)`
to
`engine= sa.create_engine("ibm_db_sa://UID:PWD@HOST:PORT)` ?

With this I get the following error:

`ibm_db_dbi::OperationalError: [IBM][CLI Driver] SQL30081N  A communication error has been detected. Communication protocol being used: "TCP/IP".  Communication API being used: "SOCKETS".  Location where the error was detected: "IP".  Communication function detecting the error: "connect".  Protocol specific error code(s): "10060", "*", "*".  SQLSTATE=08001\r SQLCODE=-30081`

Comment: did you install all the parts?

Comment: yes, I believe so.